# vim: `:q` instead of `:bdelete` when only one buffer listed

Tags: vim

I want to use a shortcut (`,q`) to **delete buffers** that I don't need but I want to use the same shortcut to **quit vim** when the current buffer is the only buffer *listed*.

I'm currently using this function:

```
function! MyClose()
    " :q if at most one buffer is loaded
    " :bdelete otherwise
    let bufcount = len(filter(range(1,bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)==1'))
    if bufcount < 2
        exe ":q"
    else
        exe ":bdelete"
    endif
endfunction
```

and then

```
nnoremap <leader>q :call MyClose()<cr>
```

but I feel that I'm not doing it right.

- Is there any better way to count listed buffers?
- Is there any better way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you could use

:help tabpagebuflist

To get a list of all existing buffers, do

```
tablist = []
for i in range(tabpagenr('$'))
   call extend(tablist, tabpagebuflist(i + 1))
endfor
```

In this case, you'd only need to check for buffers on the current tab, because doing :q will just close the tab